# Symfony 406 (Not Acceptable)

Tags: image, symfony, controller

I am trying to set image path with controller, because i choose to add my image uploaded out of web/ directory.

I create an ServeController :

```html
public function urlAction($filename)
 {
     $path = "../data/uploads/admin/";

     $response = new BinaryFileResponse($path.$filename);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
        $response->setContentDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE);

        return $response;
    
 }
```

This work from my frontend reactJs, but with i am trying to display the image on my symfony backoffice i have got error 406 Not Acceptable

In my twig template i am using {{url('url_image', {'filename' : data.filename }) }}

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
public function urlAction($filename)
{
    $path = "../data/uploads/admin/";

    $response = new Response();
    $disposition = $response->headers->makeDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE, $filename);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $disposition);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
    $response->setContent(file_get_contents($path));

    return $response;
}
```

Not sure if that will fix it though. Please try it.

Comment: I create 2 separate route one for  API && 1 one for symfony backoffice. But i am still have a little probleme to solved when i am using  url() inside a loop twig the image does not show

Comment: Hi Nicks. Sounds like a different question. Can you post a new question?